# Passing Arg in Ant

Tags: php, ant

I am working on Ant Script with following code block:

```
<target name="phplint">             
        <apply dir="${dir.publish.php}" executable="${tool.php.lint}" parallel="true" failonerror="false">
            <fileset dir="${dir.publish.php}">
                <include name="**/*.php"/>                               
            </fileset>
            <arg value="-l" />
            <srcfile/>        
            <mapper type="glob" from="*.php" to="*.html"/>        
        </apply>
    </target>
```

The command which i want to run is as below:

```
php -l index-1.php > index-1.html
```

How can i do it...! because above code is working. but i don't want `<arg value="-l"/>`

I want to pass it like `<arg value="-l"/> <arg value="> *.html"/>`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Set the `output` attribute to specify the file to which the output of your command should be redirected. Here's the [ant](http://ant.apache.org/manual/Tasks/apply.html) manual.